# Ising model with periodic structure

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models

I need pointers about whether there is such thing as a periodic Ising lattice. Those who are familiar with Ising model know that spins form a lattice in $N$ dimensions. Depending on the number of interactions per spin, this lattice can exist in 1D (two connections per spin), 2D (4 connections for square lattice), etc.

My question is whether lattices with strong periodicity have been considered. I am not talking about strong coupling as that still assumes that the probability to observe broken periodicity is unlikely, but possible. I mean that with a certain period the lattice literally replicates itself exactly, but in a way it cannot be reduced to a simple boundary condition problem... at least not trivially.

Example will be a construction like this:

$H = J_{ijkl} \sum_{<ijkl>} s_{ij} s_{kl}$

such that $s_{ij} = s_{i+1\; j+2}$ for any i,j,k,l. The sum is over near neighbors in 2D Ising model. Hence, some spins are replicas of others, not just strongly correlated. However, the periodicity is such that one cannot close the lattice under simple boundary conditions.

Comment: See [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360/are-salutations-sign-offs-and-other-politese-appropriate/361) regarding my edit.

Comment: @Ghoster There are so many seemingly arbitrary rules... Especially generic stack exchange with their policy of banning people left and right for years to come... It could be good if you guys provided some motivation for those. You work with scientists, we want to know "why", not just "what". You can boss around others, but people like us will just eventually quit using the resource and you will be left with just undergrads with their homework (don't you see it already?).

Comment: *we want to know "why"* Think of an SE Q&A as being more similar to a Wikipedia article than a social media post. Wikipedia articles don’t have chitchat. Just ask your question. The policies are set by the people who make up the community.

Comment: @Ghoster Thank you! Roger! You guys don't ban people for these things, so I get and accept it. Some editing is unavoidable, though. It is unreasonable to expect that everyone will read all the rules. I mean, people don't use blinkers on the road... But I will not greet the community anymore.

Comment: I'm confused by your notation.  What is $s_{ijkl}$?  You said your lattice is 2D, so why are you indexing your spins with four indices?  What is the difference between $s_{ij}$ and $s_{ijkl}$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, sorry, corrected

Comment: Can someone unlock the question? I provided more info. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, I can repost it but don't you try to accumulate less garbage?

Comment: I've voted to re-open (three votes are needed.)  That said, I don't see why you couldn't just treat this as a finite system with helical boundary conditions or something like that.

Comment: I think this is still very unclear. What are i and j? X and Y coordinates? Something else? What does "nearest neighbors" mean? How is this different from a normal NN Ising model, except that you shifted the summation indices?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model

Comment: @MsTais Then how does your Hamiltonian differ from the Ising model?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The Hamiltonian is the same. It is an Ising model, but spin located as {i,j} is a replica of spin located at {i+1, j+2} (not strongly correlated to, but an exact replica). You can think of them as being classically entangled (but classical entanglement is ill-defined).